# Extract data from response entity

Tags: android, json, httpresponse

I want to know how to extract data from this list.

```
Response
[
{
    "CCTID": "46204",
    "Name": "Christopher Columbus",
    "CarrierId": 64239
},
{
    "CCTID": "46208",
    "Name": "Keith Bowles",
    "CarrierId": 64239
},
{
    "CCTID": "46205",
    "Name": "Michael Jordan",
    "CarrierId": 64239
},
{
    "CCTID": "46207",
    "Name": "NESV PH",
    "CarrierId": 64239
}
]
```

How can I group this data to per driver and access the following data like a list. For example. List of drivers. Driver[0]["CCTID"] returns "46204", Driver[0]["Name"] returns "Driver[0]["CCTID"] returns "46204" Driver[0]["CarrierId"] returns "64239" so on and so forth. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I tried converting it to string. Using String s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); But I can't extract the data the way I wanted it to be.

Comment: @ljpv14 what did you try to extract the data. did you try parsing the response? if you search on so you will find many similar posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way**

```
try {
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject driver = arr.getJSONObject(i);
              System.out.println("CCTID : " + driver.getString("CCTID"));
              System.out.println("Name : " + driver.getString("Name"));
              System.out.println("CarrierId : " + driver.getString("CarrierId"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Comment: +1 for supplying what I really need. Works like a charm! Thanks!